# How do you use the defaultFieldValues parameter when calling sforce.one.createRecord method?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, sforce

Wondering how to use the new defaultFieldValues parameter on the sforce.one.createRecord() method to pass in the parent or related records.  The defaultFieldValues parameter is a Summer '17 feature that I am testing in a sandbox with Summer '17.

Documented here:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_vf_defaultfieldvalues.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm

I am trying to create a Task related to a record, and am trying to populate the Related To field, which is accessed via the whatID API Name:

Passed in as an Object:

```
var defaultsObj = {'Name' : 'Default', 'whatId','IDXYZ'}; 
sforce.one.createRecord('Object__c', myrecordTypeId, defaultsObj);
```

This doesn't seem to populate the Status or Priority fields on the Task record.

Passed in as an Array:

```
var defaultsArray = ['Status=Open', 'Priority=Normal','whatId=sfdcID']; 
sforce.one.createRecord('Object__c', myrecordTypeId, defaultsArray);
```

This also doesn't doesn't seem to populate the related record.

Answer (score 2):

Plain and simple, you can use it like this one-liner:

```
sforce.one.createRecord('Contact',null,{ 
    AccountId : "0010Y000007uaVI",  
});
```

**Caution 1:**

The this feature from Summer'17 works only if you put your Visualforce Page to API v40.0 or higher.

**Caution 2:**

Objectnames and Fieldnames are CASE-SENSITiVE! So `contact` is not `Contact` and only `Contact` is correct

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, this parameter is actually a `Boolean` that tells Salesforce to use your predefined field values that you have already set up for those fields.

For completeness, here is how you do that:

- Click the name of an action in the Buttons, Links, and Actions list
  or the Global Actions list.
- On the action detail page, click New in
  the Predefined Field Values list.
- Select the field you want to
  predefine a value for.
- Specify the value for the field.

This value can be calculated, so you have quite a lot of power to get a number of different values in here.

Ref is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this with the following:

```
var defaults = {'Name' : 'Default'};
sforce.one.createRecord('Object__c', myrecordTypeId, defaults);
```

And it's been working fine. I couldn't find documentation for it, just tried it and it worked as expected.

Comment: In your tests are you able to populate a lookup field?  Specifically one like Related To on Tasks with an whatId?


     var defaults = {'Name' : 'Default', 'whatId','IDXYZ'};
     sforce.one.createRecord('Object__c', myrecordTypeId, defaults);

Comment: @Tate I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your API version of Visualforce page is at least 40